# Help with setting up and solving differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question: Effluent is dumped into the ocean and dissipates due to currents at a rate given by $\frac{dV}{dt}$ = $\frac{k}{(1+t)^\frac{3}{2}}$, where $V$ litres is the volume of effluent at the site of the dumping, $t$ hours is the time since the dumping occurred and $k$ is a constant. If $10000$ litres are dumped initially and the effluent totally disperses eventually (so that after a long time the volume remaining is negligible), determine how long it takes for half the effluent to disperse.

My working:

So I used separation of variables to solve:

$v = \:\int \frac{k}{\left(1+t\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dt$

which is $\frac{2k}{\left(1+t\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}+C$

This is the part I am unsure of. So when $t =0$, $v = 10000$,

$10000 = \frac{2k}{\left(1+0\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}+C$

But here we have $2$ constants to solve for? Or am I interpreting the information incorrectly to start out with? Should I represent $c$ interms of $k$? How would you approach it? Is there another approach?

Answer (score 1):

1. $\int \frac{k}{(1+t)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dt= -\frac{2k}{(1+t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}+C.$
2. We have $v(t)= -\frac{2k}{(1+t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}+C.$ Hence

$$10000=v(0)=-2k+C.$$

This gives $$C=10000+2k.$$

Comment: Hi Sir Fred, thanks for the hint. But unfortunately my algebra is not strong enough and I am struggling to obtain the correct "form" as in the one in my textbook. Do you mind completing the question? Many thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote ????